# Grub menu entry misnamed

Tags: boot, grub2

I recently installed Several OSes on my computer. I have a harddrive with windows, and one that shares ubuntu studio and Kubuntu. Now, my question is, when i boot up the computer, and im loaded into grub2 (also note, im using the UEFI version), It lists ubuntu studio as just plain ubuntu. This isnt really a problem as much as just a minor peeve. I could live with it, but, I wanted to know- how does one change the name in the grub menu. I know on older versions of grub, grub.cfg was a pretty simple looking file, but now its an ugly thing with no clear answers for me. I just want to change the order of a few entries, and rename a couple ^^

Anyone able to help me?

Answer (score 0):

I used GRUB Customizer with some success. It can do what you want and has a GUI.
Install it by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

And then start it like any installed application and authenticate yourself. The program needs this as it is editing the [fstab-file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab).

Find the entry named "Ubuntu" and change it by clicking on the name twice (no double-click). Enter "Ubuntu Studio" for example. Don't forget to hit "Save" and you're good to go.

Be careful though, messing with GRUB, especially with many installed OSs on one machine, is always dangerous. ;)